# Basic vectors problem on a triangle

Tags: vectors

A student asked me the following basic problem and for some reason I just don't see the answer and it's driving me nuts. Any hints would be very appreciated.

Let $ABC$ a triangle, and a point $D$ such that we have $\vec{AD}= \frac{1}{3}\vec{AB}$. Let the point $E$ be the midpoint of $AC$. If $\vec{BM} = \lambda \vec{BE}$ and $\vec{CM} = \kappa \vec{CD}$, then find $\lambda , \kappa$ and then show that $\vec{AM} = \frac{1}{5}\vec{AB} +\frac{2}{5}\vec{AC}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints.** Since ABC is a (non flat, i presume) triangle, $(\vec{AB},\vec{AC})$ is a basis of the euclidean plane, and any vector is a linear combination of these two vectors.

As a first step, write $\vec{BE}$ and $\vec{CD}$ as a linear combination of these two vectors, taking into account that $E$ is the midpoint of $AC$, and the definition of $D$.

Then note that $\vec{BM}=\vec{BC}+\vec{CM}$. Writing $\vec{BC}$ a linear combination of $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$, you will have two different linear combinations equal to $\vec{BM}$. Now use uniqueness to identify $\lambda$ and $\kappa$.

For the last part, $\vec{AM}=\vec{AB}+\vec{BM}$, so whence you know the decomposition of $\vec{BM}$ in your basis, you will be able to deduce the result you seek.